# GIMP - How to get selection info?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, photo-editing

How would I get pixels information based on a selection using GIMP (or any other software)?

For example, just like in PS I want to select a specific region of the image and have information about its pixels (and if can, compare it with another table/values/image selection)

Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What specific kind of pixel information?  Do you mean the pixel dimensions of the selection?  If so, click Windows > Dockable Dialogs > Pointer

Comment: @BillyKerr I want to export a remap table (pixels map) to a file, how?

Comment: Do you mean the Colormap dialog?  Windows > Dockable Dialogs > Colormap.

Comment: @BillyKerr could be. Actually i want to export the colors to a .txt file. What i'm interested in is their values in hex (or anything at all!)

Comment: I've added an answer now that you have clarified what you actually want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an image in Indexed colour mode*:

1. Click *Windows > Dockable Dialogs > Palettes*
2. Find the "Colormap of image" you are currently working on
3. Right click it and choose *Export as > Text File*

The resulting text file will contain all the colours in the palette in hexadecimal.

[image]

*Note: If the image isn't in Indexed colour, convert it by clicking *Image > Mode > Indexed*.

Comment: Thanks so much!, but i don't understand. i opened the palette panel and i don't see the selection.

Comment: There is no "selection".  The palette contains all the colours in the entire image.  If you wanted just a small portion, I think you'd need to convert the mode to RGB: Image > Mode > RGB, crop the image to just the part you want to analyse, then do Image > Mode > Indexed, then find the palette and export it as text.  Once finished you could just undo all the changes (Ctrl+Z) to reverse the crop, etc.

Comment: YES!!! that's what i needed, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

### In Gimp

- The [Histogram dialog](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-histogram-dialog.html) will tell you most everything you want to know about the pixels in the selection (or the whole layer if there is no selection). You can also obtain the count of pixels in a  given value range.
- The [Pointer dialog](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-pointer-info-dialog.html) will tell you the pixel value for the pixel under the pointer using various color models (RGB, HSV, LCh, LAB...)
- The [Sample points dialog](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-sample-point-dialog.html) does a similar thing simultaneously  for up to four pre-positioned points.

Comment: Is there a way to save the selection as pixel data?

Comment: What do you mean by "pixel data"? or is [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/134103/gimp-ps-how-to-save-selection-as-pixel-remap-table) the real question?

Comment: i'm really sorry for asking twice for same purpose. But i would like to keep the question in here