# GIMP/PS - How to save selection as pixel (remap) table?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp

Using GIMP or Photoshop, either one of them. When selecting a part of the image using selection tool, how can i export this selection as a pixel map?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GIMP - How to get selection info?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/134065/gimp-how-to-get-selection-info)

Answer (score 0):

- Select>Save to channel
- In the Channels list, make sure the "Selection Mask Copy" channel is selected (it normakky should be, by default)
- File>Export: this will export the selection mask as an image (PNG or else)

To import back:

- File>Open as layers (loads the selection mask image on top of layers)
- In the Channels list, right click any of the R/G/B channels and "Channel to selection".
- Hide/remove the mask layer